# Validation styling for Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here I am validating a field in my jquery-mobile form:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("#name").val() == '')
    {
        alert("Fill in name");
    }
});
```

Obviously I don't want to do this using an alert box. How might I convey to the user instead that the field is invalid? I would like to have a solution that works on all typical mobile platforms.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LCBAg/ based on your previous question.

Comment: @Omar Thanks! But how would you give a hint to the user? For example: "Name is a required field" or something along those lines?

Comment: then use jquery-validate plugin, but for jqm its tricky.

Comment: i have updated my demo below http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LCBAg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class.

```
.required {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Add / remove it to fields:

- Text input

  ```
  $(document).on('blur', 'textarea, input', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).val() && e.target.localName == 'input') {
      $(this).closest('div').addClass('required');
    }
    if (!$(this).val() && e.target.localName == 'textarea') {
      $(this).addClass('required');
    }
  });
  ```
- Textarea

  ```
  $(document).on('focus', 'textarea, input', function (e) {
    if (e.target.localName == 'input') {
      $(this).closest('div').removeClass('required');
    }
    if (e.target.localName == 'textarea') {
      $(this).removeClass('required');
    }
  });
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LCBAg/)**

Comment: Thanks! But how would you give a hint to the user? For example: "Name is a required field" or something along those lines?

Comment: you can use a popup pointing to required field, or append a text below it.

Comment: @Baz I'll make a demo for you. it might not be a final solution, but just a hint.